# How to select a td by position of its relative th?

Tags: html, css-selectors, jsoup, html-table

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border=1> 
            <tr> 
                <th>foo</th> 
                <th>bar</th> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>1235;lsdfm*</td>
                <td>bar-value</td> 
            </tr> 
        </table> 
        <table border=1> 
            <tr> 
                <th>bar</th> 
                <th>foo</th> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>bar-value</td> 
                <td>sdfgsdfrr</td> 
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to select the `td` related to `th` containing the "foo" text. In other words, I want to select the `td` with values "sdfgsdfrr" and "1235;lsdfm*".

So far I try this css selector compatible with [Jsoup selector API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html):

```
table:has(th:matchesOwn(^foo$)) ??
```

[DEMO](http://try.jsoup.org/~p_w5jUMr7C8YrAY7vaOUxgFpHBI)

- How can I complete this css selector?
- What is the equivalent pure CSS selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible even with the selectors provided by jsoup at the moment. You can't express a column or positional relationship between elements using `:has()`, for example.

Selectors 4 proposes some additions for targeting cell elements by column, including the [column combinator `||`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#the-column-combinator) as of January 2015. However, the current text seems to indicate that `||` requires that your table have explicit `col` elements in order to work, so that won't be of use here either.

You may not have much luck doing this all with one selector. As an alternative, you could select the `th`, determine its position, and then find the `td` separately using this information. You may need to do this separately for each table, or for each column.

Comment: I would have to do it with xpath, I would use the position. However, this notion of position doesn't exist in css yet neither in the JSoup selector API.